# can the geometry element be accessed within CSVLayer in ArcGIS for JS 4.x

Tags: csv, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

I was wondering if there is a graphic or geometry element that can be access within CSVLayer in arcgis JS 4.7, I have been unable to extract the geometry which I want to save as a JSON or array that I can add to my featurelayer using applyEdits()

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `layer.queryFeatures()` method on the CSVLayer to get access to the features. Instead of fetching data from a source service like a FeatureLayer, it will access the parsed CSV data loaded locally.

Something like this.

```
  csvLayer.load()
    .then(() => csvLayer.queryFeatures())
    .then(({ features }) => console.log(features.map(x => x.toJSON())))
```

Here is a pen to demonstrate.
https://codepen.io/odoe/pen/ZRKaJN?&editors=100#